# Regex for multiple strings including spaces

Tags: regex

I need a regex for filtering out a query. For example, I get a query input as below.

```
state:CA AND country:US OR postalcode:8888
```

Here, I need to extract terms based on " AND ", " OR " (any case). Can someone please provide the regex with which I can extract terms like "state:CA", "country:US" etc?

I want to consider the spaces before and after the AND, OR as the other terms might contain "and", "or" as part of string.

```
Eg: state:OR AND country:US
```

UPDATE:
I have tried something like this

```
\sAND\s|\sOR\s
```

With this, I could find the patterns " AND ", " OR ". But, how to make it case-insensitive?

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

What flavor or regex are you using ?

If the value in your key/pair values will always be comprised of one word only, this would do:

```
\w+:\w+
```

Test it [here](http://regexr.com/3d279).

[image]

---

**Update:** 
Since your values are comprised by more than one word only, I think you should be splitting the string into key/value pairs instead of using regexes.

Here's how you could do it in **javascript**:

```
    var s = 'state:New York AND country:US OR postalcode:8888'
    var dataBlocks = s.replace(/AND|and|And|OR|Or/g, '|').split('|')
    for(var i = 0; i < dataBlocks.length; i++) dataBlocks[i] = dataBlocks[i].trim()

//your resulting array would like like 
//Array [ "state:New York", "country:US", "postalcode:8888" ]
```

The same solution, in **C#:**

```
 Regex r = new Regex(@"AND|and|And|OR|Or");
            var s = "state:New York AND country:US OR postalcode:8888";

            var keyValuePairs = r.Replace(s, "|").Split(new char[] { '|' }).Select(z =>
            {
                var keyValue = z.Trim().Split(new char[] { ':' });
                return new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyValue.FirstOrDefault(), keyValue.LastOrDefault());
            });

            foreach (var keyValuePair in keyValuePairs)
                Console.WriteLine("Key: {0}\tValue:{1}", keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. The tools is excellent for testing. The regex provided by you doesn't work in the case where there is a space or any other special character. 
(state:New york AND country:US Aus) OR postalcode:8888-121

Comment: what is the flavor of regex (where)  you are using ? javascript ? c# ?

Comment: in this case, looks like you do not need regex but rather simply splitting the string by *and/or*.